# Need To Add Custom rewrite base url for individual user

Tags: permalinks, author, rewrite-rules

I need a help regarding user custom permalinks. I have a website ad site has custom post type as "directory_tupe" like doctor, hospitals, clinics and pharmacies. WordPress user resgitered by using these categories. I need user permalink as https://themographics.com/wordpress/docdirect/doctor/steve/ instead of https://themographics.com/wordpress/docdirect/user/steve/

I have tried it by $wp_rewrite->author_base but it just set one time. I need author_base different for every user. If user registered as doctor then on author page it will be as doctor/steve and if he registered as hospital then url will be as hospital/steve

Is there any expert who can help me...

Thanks in advance